# What is the name of the android control on the screenshot?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I would like to implement the control (or fragment) shown on the right photo in my application. (The rolling cylinder used to set the text mesage limit) But what is it called? [image]

Comment: [`NumberPicker`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be a "Number Picker"
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Answer (score 0):

It is a picker.
So I think you refer to [NumberPicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html)